# NSOperationqueue i want to block main thread

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i want to block the main thread until something else is done in the background.

i used:

```
result=[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(calculate:) withObject:expression];
```

just bellow this line I am using result:

```
[self use:result];
```

i dont want to use result until it is available. 
 to achieve this I implemented

```
-calculate:
{
    [[(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] queue] waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];
    calculating result...
}
```

and still, the result is used before it is calculated. so, i didnt block the main thread. pls help me do that.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to block the main thread; it will prevent users from using the UI.

What you want is to use the result obtained in the background once it's ready.

One method is to call `-use:` at the end of the method called in the background: you define

```
-(void)calculate:(NSString*)input 
{
    .... do the calculation ...
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(use:) withObject:result];
}
```

then you just call from the main thread

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(calculate:) withObject:expression];
```

This way, you can achieve what you want without blocking the main thread.

By the way, `-performSelectorInBackgronud` has nothing to do with `NSOperationQueue`. So `[queue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished]` doesn't wait the execution of the method invoked by `-performSelectorInBackground`. 
And in any case, you shoudln't call `waitUntilAllOperationAreFinished` unless absolutely necessary.

To know when an `NSOperation` is done, you KVC the property `isFinished`. See the [NSOperation reference](http://edr.euro.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: i did it the way u said, but after 'calculate' and 'use' it didn't come back where it was. the call of calculate is made from inside a method which is implemented as part of a protocol which this viewcontroller conforms to. the problem is that after executing use, this method doesn't work anymore :hence 'it didn't come back where it was'.

Comment: Well it's not suppose to come back, because `calculate:` is run on a different thread. You need to re-design your code so that it works without coming back to the original place. That's the inherent nature of background processing and you can't fight it.

Answer (score 0):

Yuji has the correct answer that will stop your user interface from freezing.

However, if you *really do* want the main thread to block, it's pointless farming the calculation out to another thread.  Just do it on the main thread. i.e.

```
result = [self calculate: expression];
```

That is guaranteed to "block" the current thread until it is done.  If executed on the main thread, it will "block" the main thread.

Comment: doing it in the main thread (as it may take time - it's about networking) prevent me from showing a spinner. because it will show only after the result is calculated.